# how to save parent , child and grand child forms in one submit - django

Tags: python, jquery, django, database-design

i'm building an application for a mobile trading company , the is the scenario : every invoice has an unique `invoice number` and every unique `date` has several `phone models` and every phone models have a number of `IMEI` here is how i designed the database model

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    invoice_no = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    collection_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class MobileCollection(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection,on_delete=models.PROTECT,related_name='collections')
    mobile = models.ForeignKey(ModelCategory,on_delete=models.PROTECT,related_name='model_category')
    qnt = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,max_digits=20)

class Imei(models.Model):
    mobile = models.ForeignKey(MobileCollection,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    imei = models.CharField(max_length=15,unique=True)
```

i have to submit all of them in one go ! i'm not sure how to build its view , while the `MobileCollection` model should increase dynamically , and with the `qnt` field in `MobileCollection` the `Imei` forms should increase , for example if the `qnt=10` we should add 10 `Imei` forms , i thought about `inlineformset_factory` but i its not work in my case . please is there a better approach to achieve that ? thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Send multiple forms in the context and deal with all of them in the same way as you do with one form.

Example:

```
class MyView(View):
    template_name = 'my_template.html'
    collection_form = CollectionForm
    mcollection_form = MobileCollectionForm
    # and so on..

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {
            'collection_form': collection_form,
            'mcollection_form': mobile_collection_form
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context=context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        collection_form = self.collection_form(request.POST)
        mcollection_form = self.mcollection_form(request.POST)

        if collection_form.is_valid() and mcollection_form.is_valid():
            collection_form.save()
            mcollection_form.save()                
            return # your response, and so on..
    return # your forms above in the post method if the forms are not valid
```

Comment: so where is the `Imei` its not what i aske for buddy

Comment: @HunarMohammed Yes, where is it? You have to fill that in yourself, nobody here is going to do the coding for you. It is 100% clear what you need to do from here.

Comment: i know what you wrote mate , and also i add the `Imei` i just looked for a better way

Comment: The question was how to send all three forms at one go. Even if you have multiple forms you do not have multiple instances of the same form, like in formsets. If you would have a todo list it would be boring to only be able to type in one todo at the same time, so you could get multiple inputs for the same field and send all that at once. here you have quite a lot of inputs also and i dont see more than one value for each of the three objects needed at the same time.